# after appdata deletion, installation shield recover data

Tags: installation, installshield

I am creating limited version of my application in which i am deleting entire application data after application expires. For deployment i am using installation shield limited edition.

but problem is when data is deleted and app is run again, it shows windows is configuring app and again paste all application data.

i tried this:

my application data folder name is "Data", so i tried deleting entire content but keeping folder as it is. but still no success.

How do i stop this ?

Answer (score 0):

In Components view, find these files, clear their Key File settings.

Comment: I am not able to find this option anywhere, i hope you are talking about installation shield limited version only